# Can I handle a form with php if else statement in action attribute of HTML form?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, action

I am writing a form to create a login username and password.

If the account creation is successful, I would like the user to then be taken to the actual LOGIN form.

I have created a series of checks with the variable `$errcheck` being passed so the program knows what to do. If there is an error, `$errcheck` will be set to `1`. Its default is `0`.

If there are errors in the input fields, the account creation form will be displayed again and if everything is fine then it will INSERT user details into the table and take the user to the LOGIN page.

However, I can only get the page to reload itself each time after the info is added to the table. Is what I'm doing with the action part of the form even allowed? I went ahead and included all of my code in case there were any questions about it. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
        $busow_namef = $busow_namel= $owner_email = $bus_psswd = $psswd_confirm = "";                
        $busname_ERR = $busowname_ERR = $owneremail_ERR = $psswd_ERR =           
        $psswdconfirm_ERR =  "";
        $errcheck = 0;

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
            //??????????????????? Check Login information ???????????????????
            function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
            }

            if (empty($_POST["busow_namef"])) {
                $busowname_ERR = "Business owner's name is required";
                $errcheck = 1;
            } else {
                $busownamef = test_input($_POST["busow_namef"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["busow_namel"])) {
                $busowname_ERR = "business owner's name is required";
                $errcheck = 1;
            } else {
                $busownamel = test_input($_POST["busow_namel"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["bus_psswd"]))  {
                $psswd_ERR = "You must enter a password.";
                $errcheck = 1;
            } else if ((mb_strlen($_POST["bus_psswd"])) < 8) {
                $psswd_ERR = "The password must be 8-10 characters long and only include numbers and letters.";  
                $errcheck = 1;
            } else {
                $bus_psswd = test_input($_POST["bus_psswd"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["psswd_confirm"])) {
                $psswdconfirm_ERR = "Please confirm password.";
                $errcheck= 1;
            } else if  ($_POST["psswd_confirm"] != $_POST["bus_psswd"]) {
                $psswdconfirm_ERR = "The passwords do not match.";
                $errcheck = 1;
            } else {
                $psswd = test_input($_POST["psswd_confirm"]); 
                $h_psswd = password_hash($psswd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["tandc"])) {
                $checktandc_ERR= "You must accept the terms and conditions.";
                $errcheck= 1;
            } else {
                $tandc = test_input($_POST["tandc"]);
            }

            if (empty($_POST["owner_email"])) {
                $owneremail_ERR = "Please enter an email address.";
                $errcheck = 1;
            } else { 
                 $_POST["owner_email"] = (filter_var($_POST["owner_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
            }

            if (filter_var($_POST["owner_email"] , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $owneremail = $_POST["owner_email"];
            } else {  
                $owneremail_ERR = "Please enter a valid email address.";
                $errcheck = 1;
            }

            //???????????????? Connect to database ??????????????????????????
            $link = mysqli_connect('domain', 'user', 'passwd'); 
            if (!$link) { 
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error()); 
            } 

            mysqli_select_db(database, $link); 

            if (!mysqli_select_db(louisville_ky1, $link)) {
                echo "database not selected";
            } else { 
                $sql = "SELECT owner_email FROM 3bus_owners WHERE owner_email = '$owneremail' ";
                $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
                if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
                    $errcheck = 1;
                    $owneremail_ERR =  "This email is already registered. Please register with another address or click login.";
                } else {
                    $errcheck = 0;
                    $query = "INSERT INTO 3bus_owners (owner_email, h_psswd, busow_namef, busow_namel) VALUES ('$owneremail', '$h_psswd', '$busownamef',    
'$busownamel')";
                    $result2 = mysql_query($query, $link);
               } //end if num rows >0
           }//end connection check

       } // ???????????????????? end if server request method ????????????????
    ?>

    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Begin HTML FORM~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <h2>Create Business Login</h2>
    <br>
    <form method="post" action="<?php if ($errcheck = 1) { echo  
htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
} else { echo 'ownersignin.php'; }?>"> 

        Business Owner's Name:<br> 
        First Name:<br><input type="text" name="busow_namef" value="<?php echo  
$busow_namef;?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $busowname_ERR;?></span>
        <br>
        Last Name:<br><input type="text" name="busow_namel"value="<?php echo   
$busow_namel;?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php echo $busowname_ERR;?></span>
        <br>

        Business Owner's E-mail: *this will be your username for login and does not have to be posted in listing
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="owner_email" size="40"value="<?php echo  
$owner_email;?>">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $owneremail_ERR;?></span> 
        <br><br>
        Password: <input type="password" name="bus_psswd" size="11" maxlength="10">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $psswd_ERR;?></span> 
        <br>
        Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="psswd_confirm" size="11" maxlength="10">
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $psswdconfirm_ERR;?></span> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tandc">I have read and accept the 
        <a href="/termsandconditions.php" target= "_blank">Terms and 
Conditions</a>.
        <span class="error">*<?php echo $checktandc_ERR;?></span>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Login">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: The `action` attribute controls where you go the NEXT time you submit the form. It won't redirect them immediately, they have to submit the form again.

Comment: I'm confused by that, how then would a login form work?

Comment: If the registration is successful, use `header()` to redirect to the login form instead of printing the form again.

Comment: Did you ever resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

snippit from above:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php if ($errcheck = 1) { echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); } else { echo 'ownersignin.php'; }?>">
```

I have never seen a form action attribute written like this, but... try changing the "double quotes" around "PHP_SELF" to single quotes: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. That could be causing a problem because it might be getting interpreted as:

```
action="<?php if ($errcheck = 1) { echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["
```

Then, verify that this code sample didn't come from the page: "ownersignin.php". It just sounds like that would be the name of **this page** instead of the name of the page the form would redirect to.

```
echo 'ownersignin.php';
```

If this is the name of the page your code is in, it would send you in an infinite loop.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The PHP code doesn't care about the quotes in the HTML outside `<?php  ?>`

Comment: page name is different as well?

Comment: `ownersignin.php` is a different page, that's the whole point. If the form is validated he wants to send them to the signin page instead of repeating this page.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should reduce his action attribute to:
' $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ' 
and add the redirect link to the end of the php code (after all the checking is completed).

Comment: This is not ownersignin.php sample, it is definitely from createownerlogin.php. But, all this aside, now my checks aren't working and each time the submit button is pressed anything just shoots right in to my DB. I must have done something last night when I was trying to fix another issue. Geeeeez! lol

Comment: is the above code from after you worked on it last night(?), or befroe?

Comment: After, my errorchecks are no longer working and every time the Create Login button gets pushed whatever is in the form (even blanks) get added to the database.

Comment: Thank you. Whatever help you can give would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reprint the registration form when the registration is successful. Instead, redirect the user to the signin form.

After all the validation checks, do:

```
if (!$errcheck) {
    header("Location: ownersignup.php");
    exit;
}
?>
<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Begin HTML FORM~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
<h2>Create Business Login</h2>
<br>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"> 
...
```

Comment: Hey Barmar, this is giving me a blank page. I think I need to recheck my checks.

Comment: Check your PHP error log, maybe there's a syntax error somewhere.